# Voice Interactions on Android

Tags: android, voice

`getVoiceInteractor()` is always null. and `isVoiceInteraction()` is always false when I open the voice activity from another activity by touch. When you use ok google and start the activity by voice, it should work!

Is there a possibility to interact with activity by voice without starting it through voice? May be there is a setting where I can make `getVoiceInteractor()` returns non-null?